# How to find a displayversion for a specific installed program in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, registry, uninstallation

I'm trying get a displayversion for a specific program in uninstall registry path. I can get it from a direct path or get the whole uninstall listed, but I cannot get it to find a specific program based on displayname and returns displayversion. Thank you if you can help or provide instruction.

```vb
Public Function GetDisplayLink() As String
            On Error Resume Next
            Dim strRegPath As String = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{772811A3-D34B-4594-AF3E-A7C655013E62}\"
            Dim regVersion64 As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, strWorkstation, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey(strRegPath)
            Dim strDisplayLink As String = regVersion64.GetValue("DisplayVersion")
            GetDisplayLink = "DisplayLink Driver|" & strDisplayLink & "<BR>"
            regVersion64 = Nothing
        End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot get it to find a specific program based on displayname and
>   returns displayversion.

There are several ways (WMI, Shell, Msi, ...)

WMI is the simplest one but slow

A sample with **Msi**, test with "*Microsoft Silverlight*" on Windows 10 =>

```
Dim sProductName As String = "Microsoft Silverlight"
Dim nResult As UInteger = 0
Dim sProductCode As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(256)
Dim nIndex As Integer = 0
Do While (True)
    nResult = MsiEnumProducts(nIndex, sProductCode)
    If (nResult <> 0) Then
        Exit Do
    End If
    Dim nSize As Integer = 256
    Dim sbProductName As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(nSize)
    nResult = MsiGetProductInfo(sProductCode.ToString(), "InstalledProductName", sbProductName, nSize)
    If (sbProductName.ToString() = sProductName) Then
        nSize = 256
        Dim sbVersionString As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(nSize)
        nResult = MsiGetProductInfo(sProductCode.ToString(), "VersionString", sbVersionString, nSize)

        Console.WriteLine("Product: {0}", sProductName)
        Console.WriteLine(vbTab + "Code: {0}", sProductCode.ToString())
        Console.WriteLine(vbTab + "Version: {0}", sbVersionString.ToString())
        Exit Do
    End If
    nIndex += 1
Loop
```

With declarations :

```
<DllImport("Msi.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
Public Shared Function MsiEnumProducts(iProductIndex As Integer, lpProductBuf As StringBuilder) As UInteger
End Function

<DllImport("Msi.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
Public Shared Function MsiGetProductInfo(szProduct As String, szAttribute As String, lpValueBuf As StringBuilder, ByRef pcchValueBuf As Integer) As UInteger
End Function
```